# How to take table name from user input in flask?

Tags: python, php, mysql, flask, flask-mysql

```
@app.route("/CreateAScheme",methods=['GET','POST'])
def CreateAScheme():
    if request.method == 'POST':
         userDetails = request.form
         Scheme = userDetails['Scheme']
         con = MySQL.connection.cursor()
         con.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Course varchar(255) NOT NULL, Year varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(id));",(Scheme))
         MySQL.connection.commit()
         con.close()
         flash("Succesfully Created")
         return "Succesfully"
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**I am Getting an Error "not all arguments converted during string formatting"**

Comment: As an aside, you usually don't want to deal with dynamically named tables... What are you doing in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrapping a variable in parentheses, like you're doing in `(Scheme)` does nothing.

`.execute()` expects a parameter tuple, no matter if it's just an 1-tuple, i.e. `(Scheme,)`:

```
con.execute(
  "CREATE TABLE %s (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Course varchar(255) NOT NULL, Year varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(id));",
  (Scheme,)
)
```

Comment: after using backtick it works but the table name is inside a single inverted comma For ex `%s` Table Name as:- CB then the output is 'CB'. Can you tell why this happens?

Comment: Oh, yeah. `%s` are meant for variable placeholders (`INSERT INTO ... VALUES (%s)`), not for syntactic elements and keywords (such as table names), so they get escaped using those rules. If you pre-validate `Scheme` to not contain anything illegal, so it doesn't expose you to SQL injection, you can, in this particular case, use regular `%` interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

```
con.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Course varchar(255) NOT NULL, Year varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(id));" %(Scheme))
```

"Just Use regular % interpolation"

**Thank You @AKX**